# Lodash works on two objects but returns null if with three objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs, lodash

I have a weird [plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/hTSU80duOL74yF6nfeRh?p=preview)...

If I delete the 3rd item in original, `total_expenses` calculates correctly as 23196. But with the third object, `total_expenses` is null. Can anyone see something I am missing?

`total_expenses()` uses `_.reduce` to total the value of an attribute throughout the collection.

```
$scope.loan.total_expenses = _.reduce(original, function(obj){
    var grand = 0;
    grand += obj.cost;
    return grand;
});
```

Comment: You're just returning `obj.cost` in the reducing function?

Comment: Also for the first two objects, the correct total is 73196, not 23196. There are bigger issues here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `_.reduce` [docs](https://lodash.com/docs#reduce):

> The callback is bound to thisArg and invoked with four arguments;
>   (accumulator, value, index|key, collection)

The first parameter of the `_.reduce` callback is the accumulator (sum).  It is the result of the return in the callback function.  The first time the callback runs, you return `grand` (which is a number).  This becomes the `obj` parameter on the second iteration.  I don't think this is what you are intending.

Since a number has no `cost` property, you end up adding `undefined` to the first number (resulting in NaN).

This is one example that will work (however, @dfsq's example is better):

```
$scope.loan.total_expenses = _.reduce(_.pluck(original, 'cost'), function(sum, cost){
      return cost + sum;
    });
```

[Updated Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Zi8ZbKz9T52dbiMn9wNx?p=preview)

Comment: @dfsq's usage is probably better than my example. :)

Answer (score 3):

You are not using [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) function properly. Typical usage of reduce for summing values is that you provide an initial value as the third argument and return incremented value on every step of callback. Correct code:

```
$scope.loan.total_expenses = _.reduce(original, function(prev, curr) {
  prev += curr.cost;
  return prev;
}, 0);
```

In your case you have three objects in array and reduce callback will be called three times:

1. prev = 0, curr = original[0] => prev becomes original[0].cost.
2. prev = original[0].cost. curr = original[1] => prev becomes prev + original[1].cost, i.e. original[0].cost + original[1].cost.
3. etc.

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/YN35z6kDr7k4DOaQOOcr?p=preview

Comment: Can you help me understand why if I place a `console.log` in the original code block I only see 2 interations?  I see `grand` become `NaN`, but it doesn't look like `_.reduce` exits early in this case (looking at the source).

Comment: Take a look at [this demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/YN35z6kDr7k4DOaQOOcr?p=preview) of you original code. I added `prev` and `curr` parameters and printed them. If you don't provide initial value for reduce call (and you don't) then for the 1st iteration the `prev` value is going to be the first array value, and `curr` will be the second. For the second iteration `prev` will be the result of the previous step and `curr` will be the last item of your array. That's why you see only 2 iterations (you will see array.length - 1 steps if you don't provide initial value).

Comment: You could also go with this version of reduce without initial value: `$scope.loan.total_expenses = _.reduce(original, function(prev, curr) { return {cost: prev.cost + curr.cost}; });` but I find the one in my answer more comprehensive.

Comment: I like your example best as well. Wrapping in an extra object works, but seems like it shouldn't be needed.  And my example of flattening (with `_.pluck`) the cost first seems like an unnecessary step.

Comment: @DavinTryon Yes, `_.pluck` step is kind of redundant because `reduce` is already capable of doing the job, no need to make one more manipulation.